# Would it be safe enough to put this file in my static folder?

Tags: node.js, express, security

I use node.js and express.js

Hello dear community. I was wondering if for example in my web application folder where everything is stored, in my static files, let's say I want to create a game and I have a game.js file with all the game logic, the user objects, etc.

**Would it be safe enough to put this file in my static folder ? (Public Directory, Public Files).**

Comment: You need to have your .js files somwhere anyway. So, yes, putting them in `/public` sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thank's for your answer !